# Conditional ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below sample data.

```
AID    Date        Title
-----  ----------  ------
1      2011-12-12  test1
2      2011-12-12  test2
2      2011-12-12  test2
4      2011-12-12  test4
5      2011-12-12  test5
6      2011-12-13  test11
7      2011-12-13  test12
8      2011-12-13  test13
9      2011-12-13  test14
10     2011-12-13  test15
11     2011-12-14  test15
12     2011-12-14  test15
```

I need to out put like below, means I want to particular AID(5,10) in first place `order by date,aid`.

```
AID    Date        Title
-----  ----------  ------
5      2011-12-12  test5
1      2011-12-12  test1
2      2011-12-12  test2
2      2011-12-12  test2
4      2011-12-12  test4
10     2011-12-13  test15
6      2011-12-13  test11
7      2011-12-13  test12
8      2011-12-13  test13
9      2011-12-13  test14
11     2011-12-14  test15
12     2011-12-14  test15
```

Comment: In general it is considered bad practice to have a field name in your table that is the same as a SQL reserved word (ie `Date`). SQL does provide ways around it by enclosing the fieldname in square brackets, but it's still considered poor practice. Having said that, I appreciate that you may not have had a choice over the table design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY [Date], CASE WHEN AID IN (5,10) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, AID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (AID % 5) = 0 THEN (AID / 5 -1) * 5 ELSE  AID END
```

Comment: This would apply special ordering to 15, 20, 25, etc. as well. Are you sure this is what is wanted? This also seems unnecessarily more complex than the solution I suggested.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, OP just list some sample data. so I'm  assuming this rule apply to 15,20,25 etc too. If not, you are right, you answer should be best fit.